# How to remove the text from label when checkbutton is not being checked?

Tags: checkbox, tkinter, label

i'm working on this code.i want to make it display the text from the checkbutton on the label, and also remove the text when the checkbutton is not being checked.the first question is i can't remove it since the system responses

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

the other question is i want to make a shuffle button which can shuffle the text in the label.i tried `random.shuffle()` but it seems doesn't work. thanks in advance!!

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
checkbutton_frame = tk.Frame(window)
checkbutton_frame.grid(column=0, row=1)
contentvar = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(window, textvariable=contentvar,
                 bg='white', font=('Arial', 10), width=20, height=20, wraplength=50)
label.grid(column=6, row=1, padx=20,
           pady=20, columnspan=2)

cb_list = ['ray', 'kevin', 'jacky']
cb_vars = []
checked = []  
check_list = 1

def display():
    for text, var in zip(cb_list, cb_vars):
        if var.get():
            checked.append(text)
            contentvar.set(list(set(checked)))
        else:
            for i in checked:
                del checked[i]

def shuffle():
    random.shuffle(checked)

for r, element in enumerate(cb_list):
    var = tk.BooleanVar(window, False)
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, variable=var,
                        text=element, command=display)
    cb.grid(column=check_list, row=r, sticky='w')
    cb_vars.append(var)

shuffle_button = tk.Button(window, text='SHUFFLE', command=shuffle)
shuffle_button.grid(column=8, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function `display()` you have:

```
    else:
        for i in checked:
            del checked[i]
```

but checked is a string, so i will be a string. Try:

```
for i, dummy in enumerate(checked):
```

There were a few more things: the function `display()` appends to the list `checked` for checked items even if they are already there. This makes it look like the delete does not work. You can't see that you have to many of any item as you put them through a `set` before you load them into the label as `set` doesn't allow identical items.

Then you should set the `contentvar` after all processing, i.e. last in the function. Here's a version that works:

```
def display():
    for text, var in zip(cb_list, cb_vars):
        if var.get():
            if text not in checked:
                checked.append(text)
        else:
            if text in checked:
                checked.remove(text)
    contentvar.set(checked)
```

Now the texts in the label appear in the order you put them there.

The function `shuffle()` works just fine and shuffles the list `checked`. But you will have to load it into the label as well:

```
def shuffle():
    random.shuffle(checked)
    contentvar.set(checked)
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think it was of ues to you.